# DataTable do AdminLTE - Selecionar Linha / Select Row

Tags: datatable, adminlte

Estou com um projeto em andamento e uso o AdminLTE para layout.
Gostei bastante do mesmo, porém estou com um duvida a cerca do DataTable:
Como aplicar funções para pode selecionar uma linha no DataTable?

Já tentei aplicar várias dicas como:

```
$('#example2 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Porém nada dá resultado.

Alguém consegue?

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Seu erro pode estar no html também.. Poste o código para facilitar

Comment: Opa Anderson! Muito obrigado pela interação. Tentei enviaro o código HTML mas não foi possível, por aqui. Existe outro método?

Comment: Só editar a sua pergunta e colar ele, depois selecione e clique para organizar como código, tem um desenho de chaves { }

Comment: Não permite! Informa limite de caracteres! Mas creio que não seja o HTML, pois quando troco link que aponta para o CSS e JS o, o qual vem nas pastas do ADMINLTE, para os que encontrei no site DataTables.Net, funcionada. É como se o AdminLte não tivesse suporte a seleção de linhas

Comment: Ele tem sim, já usei bastante vezes, me diga oque você quer? Mudar a cor a partir da seleção?

Comment: Que bela notícia! O que quero fazer, e marcar a linha com uma cor, quando o usuário clicar nela na DataTable. Isso para poder pegar posteriormente a linha que e está marcada e edita-la (CRUD)